conda-build : Duplication of requirements in environment.yml and meta.yml
I am trying to build a python package for conda-forge. This package depends on other packages. During development I have been specifying the dev environment using environment.yml to allow other developers to easily replicate the env with conda env create --file environment.yml. So far so good, no problems, conda is amazing at this.
Now, I am trying to package with conda-build. I have created the recipe meta.yaml and duplicated the requirements from environment.yml into the build section. That's silly. I now have two different sets of requirements, one for development and one for building. I am sure there must be a simple way to have a single source of requirements, but I have not been able to find it.
I have looked in the anaconda and conda-build docs for any explanation of how to use either environment.yml for building, or meta.yaml for setting up a dev environment, so I don't need to have two sources of truth when it comes to dependencies.

The meta.yaml file is used to define the tools required to both build AND run the package.  If your package requires extra tools to build it, such as a C++ or Rust compiler, those can be specified in the requirements:build: section of the yaml file.
The dependencies the package needs when installed are defined in the requirements:run: section.  This is where you can add ONLY the other packages needed to run you package.
Here is an example that needs gcc to build the package (it must be using some C++); and separately it requires the jellyfish package to run.
requirements:
  build:
    - gcc
  run:
    - python
    - jellyfish

An environment.yaml file is entirely separate and defines the packages you are currently using.  This allows for replication of your environment by others.  However, it typically has waaaay more info that what you would put into a meta.yaml file.

"However, it typically has waaaay more info that what you would put into a meta.yaml". I have never developed a package that used different requirements for development and installation. Having two separate sources for requirements is a recipe for disaster and an unecessary complication. Is there really no other option that to meticulously keep environment.yml and meta.yaml in sync?
